# Proxy server configuration on Tor

Tags: proxy, settings

How can I ensure that the last leg of my tor proxy loop goes through a certain country on request?

Comment: Thank you works a treat.  Would be easier if this, along with number of proxy hops needed were configurable via a menu item on the browser